# Extended user login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

based on the ASP.NET Core Visual Studio emplate with individual user accounts and adding IdentityServer4 to the project as described in [IdentityServer4: Using ASP.NET Core Identity](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html?highlight=core%20identity), the relevant part for the login in the account-controller looks something like this:

```
    ApplicationUser user = null;

    // login with username and password
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
    {
      var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true);
      if (result.Succeeded)
      {
        user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
      }
    }
    if (user != null)
    {
      await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName));
      // redirect
    }
```

With this login, identityserver4 correctly issues the authentication scheme "Cookies" and creates the required tokens (access_token, id_token or whatever is configured).

Now to the problem I am having: I want to extend the username/password login with an additional option, namely an access key login. This means, that the user provides *only* a key he owns (similar to a password).
*Please put aside all security and use-case concerns you might now have.*

My code looks something like this:

```
    // login with access key
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AccessKey))
    {
      var result = await _signInManager.AccessKeySignInAsync(model.AccessKey);
      if (result.SignInResult.Succeeded)
      {
        user = result.User;
      }
    }
    if (user != null)
    {
      await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName));
      // redirect
    }
```

Simply put, I have extended the SignInManager and the UserManager with the functionality i needed. The login "logic" works correctly (the UserLoginSuccessEvent is fired properly with the expected user). However, IdentityServer4 does not seem to notice any of this. The log pretty much stays empty (except the mentioned event). My question now is: How do I *inform* IdentityServer4 that this was a successful user login and the tokens can be issued?

In case you need the implementation of the SignInManager.AccessKeySignInAsync method:

```
public async Task<(SignInResult SignInResult, ApplicationUser User)> AccessKeySignInAsync(string accessKey)
{
  if (accessKey == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessKey));
  }

  var user = await _userManager.FindByAccessKeyAsync(accessKey);
  return (user != null ? SignInResult.Success : SignInResult.Failed, user);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [Extension Grants](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ultimately PasswordSignInAsync is setting the auth cookie and that's how the authorize endpoint knows who you are. Is AccessKeySignInAsync doing the same thing?

Comment: @mackie You are right. I didn't set the auth cookie. The weird part however is, when i look at the code in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`, I don't really get how the cookie is set there.

Comment: It's abstracted away somewhat, it'll be calling SignInAsync with the cookie scheme as an argument somewhere.